# Find name in textfile

Tags: python, loops, find, text-files

im new to python (I started yesterday) and wanted to make a program, in which you can enter a name, and then searches for the name in a text file and displays if the name exists or not. If I run the program and enter a existing name, it still shows "no" and I have no idea why. Can anyone help me out?

[image: Code]

[image: Result]

Comment: Please add the code in your question, not as a screenshot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Also, if you're a beginner, I would recommend starting with text based programs. Debugging a GUI application is much more complicated, as you can see here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a small code snippet which performs this logic:

```
def find_name_in_file(name, filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as fd:
        for line in fd.readlines():
            if name in line:
                return True  # or print "YES"

    return False  # or print "NO"
```

Two things you need to keep in mind:

1. This code does not take into account case sensitivity, if name equals "Mark" and in the file the name is "mark" you will not find it (this can easily be resolved by using the "lower" function).
2. The function returns true also in cases where the file contains the word "SHMark" or "MarkSH". If you can't rely on the file having the exact name you are looking for you can add additional logic to check the word is surrounded by whitespace. I'll leave it to you to find out how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, i just added .lower() to name and file in the if statement and now everything works fine. And if i add letters bbehind the word like you said in 2. it returns false so this problem is not existing.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out for you